# Uninstall Intel Versions from Apple Silicon Mac Without Rosetta

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon, migration

I upgraded to my first Apple Silicon Mac (an M3 Pro) via Migration Assistant and have been working through the process of setting up Homebrew `/opt/homebrew` instead of `/usr/local`.

I exported a list of Intel packages before wiping my old MacBook and have them saved in a Brewfile. Is there a way to delete all the Intel-based files from my system (the ones in `/usr/local` with the list from Brewfile without installing Rosetta?

Comment: Do you have things in `/usr/local` which are not installed by Homebrew?

Comment: @nohillside I'm not sure. I'm looking through and it mostly looks like Homebrew stuff. I've tried to install anything I'm adding manually into `~/.config` and `~/.local/`

Comment: `cd /usr/local/bin; ls -l` If there is anything not symlinked into Cellar, it‘s manually installed.

Comment: Just symlinks to VSCode and Zed, which I could easily re-create. Looks like most of the symlinks are in `/usr/local/opt/`

Comment: Then it might be easiest to just empty out /usr/local.

Comment: Done — thanks. All seems well so far.